# Why generic method can't convert concrete(derived) class to it's parent class

Tags: c#, generics, inheritance

I ran into situation where I want to `Deal class` to be aware of it `DealDetail type` and vice versa, I want to `DealDetail` to be aware of `Deal type`. In future I want to have many descendants of `Deal` and `DealDetails`

I've tried to implement it using generics, but it doesn't want to compile. 
compiler gives error: Cannot implicitly convert type 'Program.ConcreateDeal' to 'TDeal'

```
public static void Main()
{
    Console.WriteLine("Hello World");

    var deal = GetDeal<ConcreateDeal,ConcreateDealInfo>();
}

public static TDeal GetDeal<TDeal, TDealInfo>()
    where TDeal : DealBase<TDeal, TDealInfo>
    where TDealInfo : DealInfoBase<TDeal, TDealInfo>
{
        return new ConcreateDeal();
}

public class DealBase<TDeal, TDealInfo> 
    where TDeal : DealBase<TDeal, TDealInfo>
    where TDealInfo : DealInfoBase<TDeal, TDealInfo>
{
    public TDealInfo DealInfo {get; set;} 
}

public class ConcreateDeal : DealBase<ConcreateDeal, ConcreateDealInfo> {}

public class DealInfoBase<TDeal, TDealInfo>
    where TDeal : DealBase<TDeal, TDealInfo>
    where TDealInfo : DealInfoBase<TDeal, TDealInfo>

{
    public TDeal Deal {get; set;} 
}

public class ConcreateDealInfo : DealInfoBase<ConcreateDeal, ConcreateDealInfo> { }
```

I expected that in method `GetDeal<ConcreateDeal,ConcreateDealInfo>()` type `ConcreateDeal` will be casted to base `Deal type` implicitly, through inheritance, but it doesn't. Where am I wrong?

dotnetfiddle: https://dotnetfiddle.net/sjtxTC

Comment: http://scotthannen.org/blog/2018/04/05/the-generic-rabbit-hole-of-madness.html

Comment: hm..seems reasonable. thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The compiler error is here:

```
public static TDeal GetDeal<TDeal, TDealInfo>()
    where TDeal : DealBase<TDeal, TDealInfo>
    where TDealInfo : DealInfoBase<TDeal, TDealInfo>
{
    return new ConcreateDeal(); // <== compiler error
}
```

You're supplying generic arguments which specify that the return type must be `DealBase<TDeal, TDealInfo>`. You can write any number of classes that inherit from `DealBase` and `DealInfoBase`, and then the method could be called with generic arguments that don't correspond to `ConcreteDeal`.

It's a little bit harder to see because of the sheer number of generic arguments. Here's a simpler version with less generic arguments for illustration. It's simpler, but it's the same thing.

```
public class Dog : Animal { }
public class Cat : Animal { }

public class Animal
{
    public static TAnimal GetAnimal<TAnimal>()
    {
        return new Dog();
    }
}
```

This won't compile for exactly the same reason.

The generic argument says that the method will return `TAnimal`. So if you call

```
var cat = Animal.GetAnimal<Cat>();
```

the return type *must* be `Cat`. But as-is the method would return a `Dog`. It doesn't make sense, so the compiler prevents it.

Comment: I think I got it. In case of generic method with return type being generic parameter,  method body can't return concrete implementation. Thank you for explanation

Comment: Sometimes the compiler errors with generics are weird, and they seem like they must be wrong. But they're always preventing you from doing something that wouldn't work. The confusing part is often figuring out what the wrong thing is that it's stopping you from doing.